# Python gRPC service for Envoy ratelimit

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, envoyproxy, grpc-python

I am trying to create a small service to respond to Envoy's rate limiting queries. I have compiled all the relevant protobuff files and the one relevant for the service I am trying to implement is here:

https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/blob/v1.17.1/api/envoy/service/ratelimit/v3/rls.proto

There is a service definition in there but inside of the "compiled" python file, all I see about it is this:

```py
_RATELIMITSERVICE = _descriptor.ServiceDescriptor(
  name='RateLimitService',
  full_name='envoy.service.ratelimit.v3.RateLimitService',
  file=DESCRIPTOR,
  index=0,
  serialized_options=None,
  create_key=_descriptor._internal_create_key,
  serialized_start=1531,
  serialized_end=1663,
  methods=[
  _descriptor.MethodDescriptor(
    name='ShouldRateLimit',
    full_name='envoy.service.ratelimit.v3.RateLimitService.ShouldRateLimit',
    index=0,
    containing_service=None,
    input_type=_RATELIMITREQUEST,
    output_type=_RATELIMITRESPONSE,
    serialized_options=None,
    create_key=_descriptor._internal_create_key,
  ),
])
_sym_db.RegisterServiceDescriptor(_RATELIMITSERVICE)

DESCRIPTOR.services_by_name['RateLimitService'] = _RATELIMITSERVICE
```

here is my feeble attempt at implementing the service

```py
import logging
import asyncio
import grpc
from envoy.service.ratelimit.v3.rls_pb2 import RateLimitResponse, RateLimitRequest


class RL:

    def ShouldRateLimit(self, request):
        result = RateLimitResponse()

def add_handler(servicer, server):
    rpc_method_handlers = {
        'ShouldRateLimit': grpc.unary_unary_rpc_method_handler(
            RL.ShouldRateLimit,
            request_deserializer=RateLimitRequest.FromString,
            response_serializer=RateLimitResponse.SerializeToString,
        )
    }
    generic_handler = grpc.method_handlers_generic_handler(
            'envoy.service.ratelimit.v3.RateLimitService',
            rpc_method_handlers
    )
    server.add_generic_rpc_handlers((generic_handler,))


async def serve():
    server = grpc.aio.server()
    add_handler(RL(), server)
    listen_addr = '[::]:5051'
    server.add_insecure_port(listen_addr)
    logging.info(f'Starting server on {listen_addr}')
    await server.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    asyncio.run(serve())
```

How am I supposed to return (or even instantiate) a RateLimitResponse back to the caller ?